# Serve content from a Google Cloud Storage bucket using Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iap

I have some content in a GCS bucket:

```
$ gsutil ls gs://my-bucket
index.html
```

I'd like to serve this behind OAuth using Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP). I'm following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto).

I've created a load balancer and and "backend bucket" like so:

[image: Load balancer configuration]

On the Identity-Aware Proxy page, however, I do not see my load balancer listed:

[image: Identity-Aware Proxy Page]

Is it possible to use IAP with a backend bucket?

Answer (score 12):

This isn't supported at the moment. The policy is applied per backend, not for the load balancer as a whole (so for example, yoursite.com/admin can be more restricted than yoursite.com/public).  However only backend *services* (ie GCE/GKE) are supported, but not backend buckets.

There is an [open feature request for backend bucket IAP support](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114133245).

Answer (score 0):

I have added a couple of changes to gcs-proxy.

so basically you can put it in cloudrun behind GLB with Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP)
and serve static sites from private GCS.

here is the fork https://github.com/mike-sirs/gcsproxy.